# Jenkins installed successfully and run on docker desktop on windows 10 yesterday , but unable to start jenkins at http://localhost:8080 today

Tags: jenkins, docker-desktop

I am new to jenkins and docker desktop. I have successfully installed docker desktop on windows 10. I have also successfully installed jenkins for docker desktop. I started jenkins and created a username to access the jenkins tool.This was yesterday. Today I started docker desktop and tried to access jenkins ,but it says,unable to access it at localhost://8080 . It says localhost:8080 can't be reached. What am I doing wrong? Please help.
Thank you in advance.
[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjhkc.jpg)
[docker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qbUT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you are not exposing the port (`-p 8080:8080`).

the output of your `docker ps` should have `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`